# AspNet WebApi System.Web.Http.SelfHost namespace is missing?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've added AspNetWebApi to my project but want to do some integration testing using the SelfHost feature.  However, I've noticed System.Web.Http.SelfHost namespace doesn't exist anywhere.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is in a separate nuget http://nuget.org/packages/AspNetWebApi.SelfHost

Comment: Note that this is a legacy package.

`"Legacy package, AspNetWebApi.SelfHost is now included in the 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost' package."`

Answer (score 0):

In case you did like jaffa - tried firstly installing webapi's package and ended up here, and tried Darrel's answer - and stumbled upon some version conflicts in installing the package (webapi's current version is > 5, while SelfHost requires WebHost 4) - just like me - then to make it work I had to play a little with uninstalling some components of the webapi (since simply uninstalling it completely did and then installing SelfHost did not work).

Here are the ones I had to remove to finally have SelfHost installed.

- **Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost**
- **Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core**
- **Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client**